# Jquery not working inside lightbox thats opening inline hidden html

Tags: jquery, lightbox

I am using lightbox evolution script. My problem is that when I am loading inline html that is on hidden, jQuery scripts are not working on it. For example tooltip script or validation script. Here is the site and code:

http://putuj.org/clickheat/index.php

If you remove from `id="login-container"` `display:none` you will see how script should work inside lightbox, but its not :(

Comment: For example, this script 

$("#user").on("focus", function(){
                $('#toolTipUserName').css({opacity: 0.0, visibility: "visible"}).stop().animate({opacity: 1.0});
               });

is working when you click on click me! button for second time.

Comment: use colorbox instead of lightbox. colorbox provides a call back function "onComplete" and in that function write the tipsy methods that you are using.

Comment: cant use colorbox as client wants lightbox evolution script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay than try this.

in the script tag write this

```
$('.lightbox').lightbox({
  'onOpen'  : function() { 
     // put your related tipsy code here
   }
});
```

Hope this will fix your problem.

Comment: Man you are life savior.. but how did you know about onOpen event, is that lightbox function or ?

Again many many thanks, I spent hours trying to fix it...

Comment: @GoranJakovljevic yes its the event of lightbox, i found it while read the js file that is used in the demo page that you provided.

Comment: Aha oke, i didnt found in documentation. Thank you Kundan.

Comment: Now IE and mozzila displays tooltips outside of window, at the left top corner.. Chrome works fine